# How to make container shutdown a host machine in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes setup in which one is `master` node and two `worker` nodes. After the deployment, which is a `daemonset`, it starts pods on both the `worker` nodes. These pods contain 2 containers. These containers have a python script running in them. The python scripts runs normally but at a certain point, after some time, it needs to send a `shutdown` command to the host. I can directly issue command `shutdown -h now` but this will run on the container not on the host and gives below error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

To resolve this, I can get the `ip address` of the host and then I can ssh into it and then run the command to safely shutdown the host.

But is there any other way I can issue command to the host in kubernetes/dockers.?

Comment: What exactly you want to shutdown, worker node or a remote server?

Comment: I want to restart the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your cluster using kube api.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/

> Accessing the API from a Pod When accessing the API from a pod,
>   locating and authenticating to the apiserver are somewhat different.
>
> The recommended way to locate the apiserver within the pod is with the
>   kubernetes.default.svc DNS name, which resolves to a Service IP which
>   in turn will be routed to an apiserver.
>
> The recommended way to authenticate to the apiserver is with a service
>   account credential. By kube-system, a pod is associated with a service
>   account, and a credential (token) for that service account is placed
>   into the filesystem tree of each container in that pod, at
>   /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token.

Draining the node you can use this

> The Eviction API

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/

But i dont really sure about on pod can drain own node. Workaround can be controlling other pod from different node.